# Can node.js files have extensions other than ".js" to differentiate client and server code in a text editor?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I am working with a node.js backend, and often when I have multiple tabs open in my text editor it is difficult to tell which javascript files that I'm editing are on the server, and which are on the client.

Is it possible to change the extension of node.js files to something like ".node" so that it's easier to tell the difference?

I realize that you could achieve this if you use typescript for either the client or the server (.ts files), but I'd prefer to use standard javascript.

If this is impossible, is there another way to differentiate server and client javascript in a text editor like vscode?

Comment: While this is technically possible, it's very bad practice. A clean folder structure would be a much better approach

Comment: I already have a clean folder structure, but when quickly switching between open tabs in my code editor sometimes I feel like my productivity is reduced by not being able to quickly differentiate client and server code. I know that if I use typescript for my node server, it would work, because I would have .ts files. I just don't want to use typescript and have to compile my server.

Answer (score 0):

You can restructurer your project as `client/...   server/...` Then, you can hover on tab to view path and clarify it .

You should use :

- Text Editor: VS Code
- IDE : Web Storm

Comment: I'm already doing this, but it's not the best solution. It takes some time for the path to pop up, and you can only see it on hover, not for all of your tabs at once.